# Angularjs button disable not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following in my page:

```
<input type="textbox" class="form-control" ng-model="reject_notes" id="rejectnotes" placeholder="Comments">

<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="!reject_notes" ng-click="rejectorder(reject_notes)">Reject</button>
```

and in my controller i have initialized:

```
$scope.reject_notes = "";
```

This worked a few days back but is not working anymore. When i enter some text in my textbox, i button is not enabling anymore. I also tried the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="reject_notes.length==0" ng-click="rejectorder(reject_notes)">Reject</button>
```

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: it should work , could you please provide me the plunker or fiidle.

Comment: @shushanthp hi, apparently my ng-model is not updating here for some reason and i have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using ng-minlength also..it disabled button until minlength not proper

```
<input type="textbox" class="form-control" name ="reject_notes" ng-model="reject_notes" id="rejectnotes" placeholder="Comments" ng-minlength="1">
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="ng-disabled='reject_notes.$error.minlength" ng-click="rejectorder(reject_notes)">Reject</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your $scope.reject_notes as undefined:

```
$scope.reject_notes = undefined;
```

then change your ng-disabled condition to "!reject_notes"

```
ng-disabled="!reject_notes"
```